# How can I download descriptors of hidden services?

Tags: onion-services, hsdir

HS publishes its descriptor to Hidden Service Directories. How or where can I find the information of this descriptor?

Comment: You can't, or at least, you're not supposed to be able to. If anyone could download descriptors from the directories, they wouldn't be called "hidden" services.

Comment: so how do you think about the answer here?
https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/retrieving-hidden-service-descriptors?rq=1

Comment: I think if this question already has an answer, you shouldn't ask a duplicate.

Comment: no, it's because the URL to the answer is no longer available. Thus, the answer is still unclear.

Comment: If you look at the comments to the answer, you find this link on the Web Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20141004110135/https://github.com/DonnchaC/tor/blob/master/scripts/retrieve_hs_descriptor.py

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. 
Btw. because I just found a paper regarding an attack to Hidden service, and it seems not an easy task to do it with some lines of code. But, yet, I will try to study more both the code and the paper.

http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2013/papers/4977a080.pdf