# Is there a way to download "hidden service descriptors" (from Windows)?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, hsdir

Before continuing, I have to say that I have read this thread (["Retrieving hidden service descriptors"](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/retrieving-hidden-service-descriptors)) and it has not solved the problem.

I am doing extensive university work on Tor, and I would like to know if there is any way to download the "hidden server descriptors" (HSD) that Tor uploads to v0 and / or v2 directory servers (HSDirs) (ie to the distributed hash table) .

I have created a hidden service, and I do not know how to download the HSD regarding my hidden service. I would like to attach it to the documentation I am creating so that readers can see what an HSD is like.

I am using the Windows 10 operating system, so I, if possible, I would like use a tool which works on this operating system.

Thank you very much!

(Sorry for my  English; English is not my mother language).